# Paclet specialized for circular statistics?

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics

I recently came across Lior Kogan's "[Circular Values Math and Statistics with C++](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190833/Circular-Values-Math-and-Statistics-with-Cplusplus)". Is there a similar Mathematica Paclet for circular statistics analysis -- that includes NonlinearModelFit methods *specifically designed* with the expectation there will be variables that are periodic?

Comment: Could you perhaps add an example of a problem you would like to solve?

Comment: There is certainly no built-in functionality for circular/spherical/directional statistics (unless you count `VonMisesDistribution[]`); I too would be interested in seeing if an enterprising user has written such functionality.

Comment: The provided link does not work.

Comment: @AntonAntonov -- Thanks for the head's up.  I'll adjust the original post shortly with alternate links.

Comment: About 6 to 7 years old:  https://github.com/skidvision/CircularStatistics.